# Bethe ansatz eigenfunctions of Hubbard model

Tags: condensed-matter, wavefunction, many-body

I want to calculate the exact eigenfunctions of Hubbard model by using Bethe ansatz. I have solved the periodic boundary condition equations (Lied-Wu equations) and have the values of the momentum "$k$"s, for $4$ sites and $2$ electrons model. Now I use the following formula for the wavefunction (attached as image):

[image]

the amplitudes $\psi(x_1,x_2,..x_{N_e})$ are complex valued for general $k_1$ and $k_2$. But when I diagonalize the Hubbard Hamiltonian for $4$ sites and $2$ electrons, all the amplitudes of the  eigenfunctions are real valued. What am I doing wrong?